# jquery inArray not found value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find `selected value` in `array` but what i tried so far not working:

```js
var array = [0, 74];
$('select').change(function() {
  var selected = $('select option:selected').val();

  if ($.inArray(selected, array) != -1) {
    alert('found');
  } else {
    alert('not found');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option value="0" selected="selected">----</option>
  <option value="59">ss</option>
  <option value="61">aa</option>
  <option value="62">zz</option>
  <option value="60">yy</option>
  <option value="74">xx</option>
</select>
```

it works with `$.each` but i don't want use any loop my goal is get this with `inArray`. if selected value is `0` or `74` it should alert `found` but it not works.

Comment: change the array to `var array = ["0", "74"];`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/
Comparison is "Strict", either convert "array" to type String or type cast "selected" to INT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val` returns a string and `inArray` does strict comparison

```js
var array = [0, 74];
$('select').change(function() {
  var selected = $('select option:selected').val();

  // convert to a number
  if ($.inArray(+selected, array) != -1) {
    alert('found');
  } else {
    alert('not found');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option value="0" selected="selected">----</option>
  <option value="59">ss</option>
  <option value="61">aa</option>
  <option value="62">zz</option>
  <option value="60">yy</option>
  <option value="74">xx</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf()` function for find in array.

Chanhe type selected to integer `parseInt()`  (array is integers)

```js
var array = [0, 74];
$('select').change(function() {
  var selected = parseInt($('select option:selected').val(), 10);
  if(array.indexOf(selected)!=-1){
    alert('found');
  } else {
    alert('not found');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select>
  <option value="0" selected="selected">----</option>
  <option value="59">ss</option>
  <option value="61">aa</option>
  <option value="62">zz</option>
  <option value="60">yy</option>
  <option value="74">xx</option>
</select>
```